# Will Older Android Devices Run ES6 with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

I'm creating a hybrid app using Angular wrapped in Cordova. I have learned that on my Android emulator running Android 9 that it will only run correctly if I compile the angular app with es5 target. I am wondering if this is true for only for the emulator or if an Android 9 device would run the es6 without problem.

Also, is there any performance benefit of es6 over es5?

Thanks

Comment: "*Also, is there any performance benefit of es6 over es5?*" it depends. ES6 is merely a spec, it doesn't directly have performance relation, because it's implementation dependent. Still, it does introduce constructs like Sets and new methods that make certain tasks easier than not having standardised mechanisms. You could easily leverage ES5 features to do those (that's how transpiling works, after all) but there are cases where ES6 makes some implementations of tasks more convenient. So, *technically* you shouldn't see much of a performance impact but you *might* under the right conditions.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ that's very helpful :)